# Write to a file from RAISE NOTICE in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, notice, raise

I have one sample function in postgresql and it raises a notice.

Sample function -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION raise_test() RETURNS TEXT AS
$body$
DECLARE
 retStr TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT current_timestamp into retStr;
    RAISE NOTICE '%', retStr ;
    RETURN retStr;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is there any way to update above function so that the entire notice stored into a file?

Like if I hit "call raise_test();" and in my specfic location I 'll have one out.txt with the entire notice printed.

PS. I hv tried to insert the notice in to a temp table then use -

```
COPY (select * from temp) TO '\home\pgsql\out.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

The reply depends on your possibilities. You cannot to do this work with usual tools. There are two possibilities - first - use some PostgreSQL extensions with possibility to create file  and write to file like [Orafce](https://github.com/orafce/orafce) or you can write own C extension that will use [PostgreSQL log hook](http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-logs-json/) - and then you can do what you want.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to have RAISE NOTICE go to a file, rather than show up on the screen. I have done with storing NOTICE in a temp table then print it to a flat file. Any way to skip the temp table part ? Only pgadmin and Postgres db is in my hand.

Comment: you can enforce RAISE NOTICE to log. But it is all, what you can without programming in C