# PostgreSQL : when using RAISE NOTICE in psql, can I avoid the "NOTICE :" prefix from the output

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I am trying to port some functionalities from Oracle PL/SQL to PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL.

As it seems to be the most common way of printing text to screen, I would like to use the RAISE NOTICE to display messages on the standard output, output that would go to a file using **-o file.txt** argument of psql.

Problem is that the message level (here RAISE NOTICE 'msg' => level : NOTICE) goes before the message in the output (prefix) and I don't like it.

E.g. this PL/pgSQL code when run in psql :

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'my message';
END; $$;
```

will generate this output :

```
NOTICE:  my message
```

**Is there any way to remove the message level before the message itself ?**
(here I would like to avoid "NOTICE :" prefix).

PS : I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101306/retreiving-original-notice-text-from-postgresql) where the same question is asked in the context of psycopg2, but here my context is the **psql** tool.

Also [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566641/write-to-a-file-from-raise-notice-in-postgresql) is close to what I'm trying to do here but the answer is not satisfying to me.

NB: I'm using latest PostgreSQL and psql (version 12.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. This is the behaviour of **libpq** - Postgres driver, and psql uses this driver.

Comment: OK. Thanks Pavel, I knew you can reply on this one :)
Sad for me but OK, I might use the sed tool to get rid of this.
However, this would be great to have an option for this in psql (same as "client_min_messages", like "client_show_message_level" for example).
Thanks for your great work in PostgreSQL by the way.

Comment: Maybe you use notification for some wrong purpose. Maybe, I don't know.

Comment: OK, that's interesting, I'm open to suggestion.
Thing is .. what if I can't use orafce, how would you do the equivalent of a dbms_output.put_line using pure postgreSQL code ?

Comment: For example in Oracle, when using "set serveroutput on" + "dbms_output.put_line" I can generate a file without using "utl_file" package, so I can run my script on the application server and get the generated file in a local folder of the app server

Comment: You can store data to temporary table. It's very similar to what dbms_output does.

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply, I will try that and we'll surely also use orafce when needed. Keep up the good work.